# Mongodb query to get count of field based on the value for a matching string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following Mongodb document.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("62406bfaa1d66f8d99c6e97d"),
  "skill": "Programming Language"
  "supply" : [
    {
        "employeeName" : "A1",
        "skillRating" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A2",
        "skillRating" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A3",
        "skillRating" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A4",
        "skillRating" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A5",
        "skillRating" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A6",
        "skillRating" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A7",
        "skillRating" : 2
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A8",
        "skillRating" : 2
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A9",
        "skillRating" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A10",
        "skillRating" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A11",
        "skillRating" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A12",
        "skillRating" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A13",
        "skillRating" : 2
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A14",
        "skillRating" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "employeeName" : "A15",
        "skillRating" : 4
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I write a Mongodb query to produce the following output (i.e.: Get the count of occurrence of each value for a matching skill)

```
{
  skillName : "Programming Language",
  skillRating1: 0,  <-- Count of skillRating with value 1
  skillRating2: 3,  <-- Count of skillRating with value 2
  skillRating3: 5,  <-- Count of skillRating with value 3
  skillRating4: 7,  <-- Count of skillRating with value 4
  skillRating5: 0  <-- Count of skillRating with value 5
}
```

[Note: I am learning to write Mongodb queries]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $unwind: "$supply"
},
{
  $group: {
  _id: "$supply.avgSkillRating",
  cnt: {
    $push: "$supply.avgSkillRating"
  },
  skill: {
    $first: "$skill"
  }
 }
},
{
  $project: {
  z: [
    {
      "k": {
        "$concat": [
          "avgSkillRating",
          {
            $toString: "$_id"
          }
        ]
      },
      "v": {
        $size: "$cnt"
      }
    }
  ],
  skill: 1
 }
 },
 {
  $replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: {
      "$mergeObjects": [
      {
        "$arrayToObject": "$z"
      },
      {
        skillName: "$skill"
      }
     ]
    }
  }
},
{
$group: {
  _id: "$skillName",
  x: {
    $push: "$$ROOT"
  }
 }
},
{
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": "$x"}
  }
 }
])
```

Explained:

1. Unwind the supply array
2. group avgSkillRating to array cnt ( to be possible to count )
3. form z array with k,v suitable for arrayToObject
4. mergeObjects to form the keys and values
5. group to join the objects and leave only single skillName
6. replace the root document with the newly formed document with the necesary details.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d1WR24ce6O9)

Answer (score 2):

You can go with aggregation,

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$group` to get the sum of avg by _id and the avg
- `$arrayToObject` to make the field to object with the help of `$concat`. Because we need the skillRating1,skillRating2...
- `$replaceRoot` to get the object to root document
- `$project` to decide whether to show or not

Here is the code,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$supply" },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": { _id: "$_id", avg: "$supply.avgSkillRating" },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 },
      "skill": { "$first": "$skill" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id._id",
      "skill": { "$first": "$skill" },
      "data": {
        $push: {
          k: {
            $concat: [ "avgSkillRating", { $toString: "$_id.avg" } ]
          },
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$addFields": { "data": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" } } },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": [ "$$ROOT", "$data" ] }
    }
  },
  { "$project": { data: 0 } }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N8dXqRy4HK8)**

Answer (score 2):

Here's another version that also reports `skillRating`s with a zero count.  This aggregation pipeline is essentially identical to [@varman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71638531/1409374) and adds a complex (to me anyway) `"$set"`/`"$map"` to create the extra fields.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$supply"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": { "_id": "$_id", "avg": "$supply.avgSkillRating" },
      "count": { "$count": {} },
      "skillName": { "$first": "$skill" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id._id",
      "skillName": { "$first": "$skillName" },
      "data": {
        "$push": {
          "_r": "$_id.avg",
          "k": { $concat: [ "skillRating", { $toString: "$_id.avg" } ] },
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "data": {
        "$map": {
          "input": { "$range": [ 1, 6 ] },
          "as": "rate",
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "idx": { "$indexOfArray": [ "$data._r", "$$rate" ] }
              },
              "in": {
                "$cond": [
                  { "$gte": [ "$$idx", 0 ] },
                  {
                    "k": {
                      "$getField": {
                        "field": "k",
                        "input": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$data", "$$idx" ] }
                      }
                    },
                    "v": {
                      "$getField": {
                        "field": "v",
                        "input": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$data", "$$idx" ] }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "k": { $concat: [ "skillRating", { $toString: "$$rate" } ] },
                    "v": 0
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$set": { "data": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" } } },
  { "$replaceWith": { "$mergeObjects": [ "$$ROOT", "$data" ] } },
  {  "$unset": [ "data", "_id" ] }
])
```

Try it [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xl4Jg4IiMzk).

Comment: That's great answer, I couldn't do it, because not specified the range,